# Postgres PGSimpleDataSource changing database name

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, datasource

This is what I am trying, I want to connect to a default admin database, create a new database and immediately switch to it.

Below is my pseudo-code:

```
// Create a new datasource
dataSource = PGSimpleDataSource()
dataSource.setURL("jdbc:postgresql://mydbserver:5432/admin")
dataSource.setUser("test")
dataSource.setPassword("testing")

// get connection to admin db and create a new database named 'mynewdb'
connection = dataSource.getConnection()
cs = connection.createStatement()
cs.executeUpdate("create database mynewdb")
cs.close()
connection.close()

// switch to the newly created database using the **same datasource**
dataSource.setDatabaseName(mynewdb)
connection_to_new_db = dataSource.getConnection()
ps = connection_to_new_db.preparedStatement()

....start doing transactions on the newly created database...
....start doing transactions on the newly created database...
```

Above code seems to work fine.

Questions:

1. is it legal to change the database name on the fly on an existing datasource? Are there any repercussions?
2. is this the right way to accomplish what I am trying or is there a better way?

Comment: It's probably the "best" way because there is no other way

Comment: The alternative would be to use `DriverManager.getConnection` to create the connection to the admin db, create the new database and only then configure the data source.